# How to set these blocks in one line?

Tags: html, css

I can't set these buttons horizontally. Any ideas? I am playing with this about 2 hours so I write here. Effect should be like image below, it isn't actually. Thank you for all responses, I appreciate it.

[image: desired effect]
css

```
.image{

    float: right;
    height: 680px;
}


blockquote {

    background: url(http://www.studiopress.com/wp-content/uploads/bg-quote1.png) no-repeat;     
    color: #a5a4a4;
    font-style: italic;
    margin: 30px;
    padding: 30px 30px 30px 50px;     
}  




/* Google Fonts */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);


.link {
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #55acee;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #55acee;
  transition: .3s;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  -moz-transition: .3s;
  -o-transition: .3s;
}

.link:hover {
  color: #2ecc71;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #2ecc71;
}

/* css for the shiny buttons */
.bb {
  cursor: pointer;

  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 22px;
  transition: .3s;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  -moz-transition: .3s;
  -o-transition: .3s;
  display: inline-block;
}

.bb:hover {
  cursor: url(http://cur.cursors-4u.net/symbols/sym-1/sym46.cur), auto;
}
.blue {
  color: #55acee;
  border: 2px #55acee solid;
}

.blue:hover {
  background-color: #55acee;
  color: #fff
}

.green {
  color: #2ecc71;
  border: 2px #2ecc71 solid;
}

.green:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}

.red {
  color: #e74c3c;
  border: 2px #e74c3c solid;
}

.red:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}

.purple {
  color: #9b59b6;
  border: 2px #9b59b6 solid;
}

.purple:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #9b59b6;
}

.orange {
  color: #e67e22;
  border: 2px #e67e22 solid;
}

.orange:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #e67e22;
}

.yellow {
  color: #f1c40f;
  border: 2px #f1c40f solid;
}

.yellow:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f1c40f;
}

.buttons {
  padding-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}




</style>
```

html

```
    <br><br><br><br>
<div class="container">

    <div class="jumbotron">


        <img class="image" src="../assets/media/img/laskaniemiecka.png">

        <div class="blockq">

            <blockquote> The blockquote element is a mechanism for marking up a block of text quoted from a person or another document or source. It may be just a few lines, or it may contain several paragraphs.</blockquote>
        </div>


         <div class="buttons" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';">
            <div class="bb blue">Powtórki</div>

            <div class="bb purple">Lekcje audio</div>

        </div>







        <br><br><br><br><br>




    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this code:

```
.buttons div {
  display: inline-block;

  /* height:80px; 
  padding: 0px 30px;
  line-height:80px; */
}
```

Comment: I tried this, problem is that it's not working I don't know why

Comment: sure, I think that image width blocks inline property of these buttons

Comment: solution can be setting these buttons overlaping everything, especially image

Comment: can you make a demo with the image?

Comment: I changed many things in CSS. I don't know if this is similar to what you want, but you can have a look. http://jsfiddle.net/georgemarts/hgdp0v8f/

Comment: image is missing :/ i cant accept that version. Do you have any ideas to get solution of this?

Comment: actually, image isn't missing..instead of having an image element, I set the image as a background-image for the jumbotron. But, it seems that this doesn't be what you want..

Comment: it's not good solution to set the image to background of jumbotron. Best way to do this would be if somehow these buttons would be over this image. Then it would be desired effect like on the picture above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71381/discussion-between-tom-and-georgemarts).